# Does breeze support inherited tables?

Tags: breeze

I have a table that inherits from another table. When I run the project, I get the following error: unable to get property 'propertyref' of undefined or null reference ...Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:  As of v 1.3.1 Breeze now DOES support inheritance.

Breeze does not yet support inheritence. But it is high on our todo list. Please vote for this on the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3083057-support-inheritence-in-the-object-model).  We take these suggestions very seriously in determining what to work on next.